# SQL Query Using Known SUM Value

Tags: mysql

I cannot get this command to work, the SUM of column2 is known (400) but I can't use it to query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE SUM(COLUMN2) LIKE '400'
```

> `#1111` - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Your statement makes no sense.  Provide sample data and desired results, and explain what you are trying to do.  Although changing the `WHERE` to a `HAVING` would fix the syntax error, the query still would not make sense.

Comment: you can't use aggregate functions in WHERE, instead use SELECT * FROM `mytable` GROUP BY(COLUMN2) HAVING SUM(COLUMN2) LIKE '400'

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo You should add it as an answer, since it is the right one.

Comment: @JorgeCampos ok, I have added it as an answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, changing the WHERE to a HAVING fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aggregate functions in `WHERE`, instead use:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY(COLUMN2) HAVING SUM(COLUMN2) = 400
```

Comment: sum = 400 it the right way! its a numeric operation.